# Undefined offset in PHP

Tags: php, preg-match

When I tried following code:

```
function getusername($input){
    //parse the result
    preg_match("/<username>(.*)?<\/username>/", $input, $username);
    return $username[1]; // Line 4
}
```

It gave me this error:

> Undefined offset on line 4.

Comment: Are you sure `$input` matches your regex?

Comment: It would help if you added the $input you are running the function on.

Comment: Just a thought (I already upvoted an answer), looks like you are parsing XML, so why not use SimpleXML instead ?

Comment: @All: I was passing wrong XML. Thank you all.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: I accept it is YetAnotherRubbishQuestion. As I mentioned in question I am not even familiar with PHP and had to work with few PHP code.Thanks for your comments to help me out and letting me know that it is a YetAnotherRubbishQuestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What blunder am I doing ?

Well, it seems `$username[1]` does not exist. This might happen if the regular expression does not match. I would change it to:

```
function getusername($input){
    preg_match("/<username>(.*)?<\/username>/", $input, $username);
    if( count( $username ) > 0 ) {
        return $username[1];
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Or even `if (preg_match("/<username>(.*)?<\/username>/", $input, $username)) { return $username[1]; } return false;` since `preg_match` returns the number of matches.

Comment: shouldn't `count($matches)` be `count($username)`?

Answer (score 0):

It means that you are trying to access a key in the array which doesnt exist. So it seems that your `$username` variable doesnt have the key 1. Remember that in programming you usually start counting at 0, so the first value would be `$username[0]`.

You can visualise your username variable by calling `var_dump`, as such:

`var_dump($username);`

Answer (score -1):

There are various possibilities.

1.) The site which you are trying to access doesn't allow bots or have some security feature which can stop the bot from accessing the site. To check whether the site is redirecting or not, print/echo the variable in which you have all the stuff stored.

2.) The text expression is not written in the correct format, Logically incorrect where it produces result as empty set.